# Is it possible to reduce sway when aiming with the Tranquilizer Rifle?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

When aiming with the scope with the Tranquilizer Rifle there is a lot of sway, which can make aiming very difficult. Is there anyway to reduce or eliminate this sway?

Comment: Crouching or purchasing the stability aug doesn't affect it like other guns?

Comment: crouching makes no difference. As for the stability aug, doesn't that only have an affect when you're moving?

Comment: Also, stability doesn't affect sway, only your crosshairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just did some testing.

The Aim Stabilizer completely eliminates any sway when fully upgraded, as well as eliminating crosshair growth while moving (which can be accomplished by using the laser sight weapon mod anyway). The Recoil Reducer only reduces the crosshair movement brought on by firing in long bursts, it doesn't affect sway in any way.

Comment: While it doesn't sway any more, it _still_ feels like the aim is off (even if accounting for projectile motion).

Comment: If you install the target leading system, then it shows the bullet drop as well as how far ahead to aim. But yes, it takes getting used to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to buy the 2 Aim Stabilizing augments and you should install the Target Leading weapon mod in the tranq rifle.

The description for the stability mod says it reduces movement penalties to your aim. I take that to mean *involuntary* movements, the kind we all make, even when trying to be still. Since I purchased the augs, I have had no trouble aiming with the tranquilizer rifle.